# What happens when you use an electric field to match atom oscillations?

Tags: solid-state-physics, atomic-physics, atoms

I've been thinking about this question for the last few days:

"*What happens when you either use an electric field or sound / light to match the frequency of the atomic lattice?"*

What would happen to the material? I think it would behave as if it entered another aggregation phase at that moment.

Comment: The nearest thing to what you seem to be describing is an [Optical Phonon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonon#Acoustic_and_optical_phonons): look this up and you might find some of the answers you seek.